# copy the content of an xml attribute into an xml element using an xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, element, transformation

I have the following part of an xml file

```
<ns1:Main ns1:IdentifiantMain="token_new" ns1:Operation="Aucune">
          <ns1:elementA>token_old</elementA>
        </ns1:Main>
```

and I want to have a transformation in order to create a new xml, that looks like this:

```
<ns1:Main ns1:IdentifiantMain="token_new" ns1:Operation="Aucune">
      <ns1:elementB>token_new</elementB>
    </ns1:Main>
```

where basically the old element is remvoed and the new element "elementB" is filled with the content of the Attribute "ns1:IdentifiantMain"

I have tried to use the followint xsl file, but actually. it doesn't work.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://xml.rsi.fr/schema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.rsi.fr/schema">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:Main">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <ns1:elementB>
            <xsl:value-of select = "@ns1:elementB/ns1:IdentifiantMain"/>
        </ns1:elementB> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xsl:copy-of` is a deep copy that will copy the `ns1:Main` element and it's descendants. Since you want to change the child element, you would want to use `xs:copy`.

`xsl:copy` is a shallow copy, and is only copying the `ns1:Main` element. If you wanted to also copy it's attributes, you could then add either `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` to explicitly copy the attributes or `<xsl:apply-templates match="@*"/>` which would look for any matching templates and hit the generic identity template above, which would copy the attributes. Then, inside of the `ns1:elementB`, select the value of the `@ns1:IdentifiantMain`. Since your template matches `ns1:Main`, that is the context that your XPath is relative from.

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:Main">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <ns1:elementB>
      <xsl:value-of select = "@ns1:IdentifiantMain"/>
    </ns1:elementB> 
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, rather than matching on the `ns1:Main` element, match on the element that you intend to replace, `ns1:elementA`. Then, instead of copying that element inside of your template, construct the `ns1:elementB` and then get the value of the `ns1:elementA`'s parent element's `@ns1:IdentifiantMain`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://xml.rsi.fr/schema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.rsi.fr/schema">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:elementA">
        <ns1:elementB>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@ns1:IdentifiantMain"/>
        </ns1:elementB> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```